# Unable to get the SpeakerId associated with a Phone Number in Amazon Connect VoiceID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-connect

I am trying to get the unique SpeakerId associated with the calling phone number, I have used all the SDKs provided by amazon connect for VoiceID.

```
describeSpeaker
describeSpeakerEnrollmentJob
listSpeakerEnrollmentJobs
listSpeakers
```

So far I have only got this as response,

```
"SpeakerSummaries": [
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2023-01-16T12:13:40.759Z",
            "CustomerSpeakerId": "123",
            "DomainId": "QWpiv9aYj7o3teNNuegSrY",
            "GeneratedSpeakerId": "id#MUnL8pdYSFxqG7LmmKBP0Y",
            "LastAccessedAt": "2023-03-06T12:06:52.000Z",
            "Status": "ENROLLED",
            "UpdatedAt": "2023-03-06T12:04:15.000Z"
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2023-01-16T12:16:45.053Z",
            "CustomerSpeakerId": "555",
            "DomainId": "QWpiv9aYj7o3teNNuegSrY",
            "GeneratedSpeakerId": "id#3Y18U4eNPvwGC9YqPDDmU0",
            "LastAccessedAt": "2023-01-16T12:20:03.000Z",
            "Status": "ENROLLED",
            "UpdatedAt": "2023-01-16T12:18:35.000Z"
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2023-05-12T12:53:40.329Z",
            "CustomerSpeakerId": "1111",
            "DomainId": "QWpiv9aYj7o3teNNuegSrY",
            "GeneratedSpeakerId": "id#9JOSNJJoqxfzgSOvPE12pV",
            "LastAccessedAt": "2023-05-12T13:19:37.000Z",
            "Status": "ENROLLED",
            "UpdatedAt": "2023-05-12T12:57:14.000Z"
        },
        {
            "CreatedAt": "2023-05-12T12:59:34.997Z",
            "CustomerSpeakerId": "Timeout",
            "DomainId": "QWpiv9aYj7o3teNNuegSrY",
            "GeneratedSpeakerId": "id#HEBYSjw8j1GtF6urdpFmlI",
            "LastAccessedAt": "2023-05-12T12:59:34.000Z",
            "Status": "ENROLLED",
            "UpdatedAt": "2023-05-12T12:59:34.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

Any Help would be apprecaited

Answer (score 1):

The VoiceID system only associates the callers voice with a Speaker object. The speaker object isn't linked to anything directly in Connect, e.g. a phone number or Connect customer profile.

When a customer calls in and is enrolled in VoiceId by an agent, the system requires the `CustomerId` attribute to be set. This defines the value for the  `CustomerSpeakerId` in the Speaker object. It can be set to anything you like (a account id from a CRM for example), with the limits that the string can only include alphanumeric characters and the - and _ symbols.

Assuming that the `CustomerSpeakerId` has been set to an account number from your CRM, then to find the phone number associated with the VoiceId you need to do a lookup of the `CustomerSpeakerId` field against your CRM to get any associated phone number.

In the reverse, if a caller calls in you could perform a lookup of your CRM to get an account number based on the callers phone number. If the phone number lookup fails (or you can't do a lookup for some reason) you can get the caller to enter their account number manually.

Then set the `System - CustomerId` attribute to that account number in a set attributes block. Then when you use the `CheckVoiceId` block it can return the authentication status for the caller against that account.

You could theoretically set the CustomerId to a phone number (being aware that CustomerID can't include the + symbol) but then the Caller can't be authenticated unless they call from that number. I'm not sure what the use case is for VocieId when you aren't associating the person with an account of some kind :)